# Why were we rejected under 214b? USA

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I have an Indian passport

I was planning on travelling to the USA to visit Orlando Florida with my family

- I have a mortgage on my house
- I have permanent residency in the UK
- I have a job where I've been working for over 14 years
- My husband and two boys were travelling under ESTA's and have British passports
- My children are going to go to good universities and living at home while doing so
- I had bank statements with me
- We bought the tickets, and had proof of return flight tickets, hotel tickets and insurance

I had evidence of everything.

The first time I had the interview I was rejected because I didn't have the airline tickets and I didn't show my bank statements, and I believe their was a lack of communication. I managed to get another appointment within 1 and a half weeks, as I kept checking for cancellations as we wanted to go on this holiday really badly.

I managed to get another interview, I got to the interview, everything was fine until I was asked how I got another appointment so fast.

she (Interviewer) said: 'you can only get one after 6 months'

I said (Me): 'I phoned up the US embassy to ask how we could get an earlier appointment and they told me to keep checking for cancellations and that's how we managed to get an earlier appointment'.

She said (Interviewer): 'Is this an emergency, is that how you got the appointment.'

I said  'No, we managed to get one by checking every hour online for cancellations.'

The interviewer looked around for someone, I don't know who she was looking for and said 'Sorry you have been refused.'

I said 'Why have I been refused, I've got all these documents.'

She said 'It's on the paper mam, please could you go other people are waiting.'

I then left, the paper said nothing specific about the refusal, it just said we were rejected under 214b.

What happened, gutted that we've had to cancel this holiday ?

Could it have been that I've never been anywhere else other than India? (I live in the UK)

Additional info - I should add she also asked 'How I got this visa appointment so early as her first question, but she brushed that question off initially and went onto the next ones. It's like she got panicky towards the end and thought that I had done something wrong to get this appointment.

Comment: It is we just had it earlier today at the London Embassy. Everyone is extremely sad, especially the kids.

Comment: Wow... I would file a formal complaint if I were you, seems totally ridiculous.

Comment: I mean if you compare it to the UK, they focus the entire interview on your documents, which it should be, but in the USA it's like they don't care what documents you have. 

I remember reading that 'they have specialist interviewers who are able to asses someone in a couple of minutes'. It's just a bit of a silly system, atleast please give me a reason for refusal

Comment: @JSLavertu Good luck with that.

Comment: @zombie No it's not.  You could look perfect on paper and that may be totally phony.

Comment: Why haven't you bothered to obtain British citizenship, then? If your post is accurate, then you were probably qualified years ago.

Comment: @Michael: this would mean loss of Indian citizenship - India is very strict on that.

Comment: Many Indians here in US, who went through the procedure, told me it is really PITA to do (lots of forms and papers). Also non-citizens cannot buy agricultural land, although can inherit one. But the major issue is the community there, labeling you as a non-patriotic.

Comment: It cost £1000 to become a british citizen, we never really needed it till now I also have land in india which I'm trying to sell at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to make something out of what you said, but at least I can answer the question:

> Could it have been that I've never been anywhere else other than
>   India?

Yes, it definitely could. The US Consulates are suspicious of people who claim to go to USA for sightseeing, while they haven't done any even in their neighbor countries. You said you were going to Orlando - probably for Disneyland - but there are Disneylands much closer to you; did you explain why are you going to Orlando, when there is DisneyLand in Hong Kong (if you're in India) or in Paris (if you're in UK) are much closer?

**Edit:** Do not assume the Consular Officer would think himself/herself of possible reasons why you *could* prefer Orlando to Paris. They might ask you, but please do not expect that to deliver your story. When applying for a visa, you need to be proactive and address anything which might be interpreted as red flag proactively. The easiest way to do this is to print some kind of informal statement, and just give it to the Consular Officer. This statement should address anything you think is a red flag in your case, such as:

- Why aren't you a British citizen yet;
- Why haven't you traveled around Europe, which is very close;
- Why you want to go to Orlando and not to other, closer destination with the same attractions;

Those are obvious questions the Officer would be concerned about. And if you do not address those proactively, they'd have to guess the reasons. And not only their guess might not be in your favor - they are required **by law** to be skeptical; the immigration law requires them to assume everyone trying to get the US visa intends to remain illegally **unless proven otherwise**. The burden on this proof is on you. This might look unfair, but those are the rules.

Also it is very strange that you got rejected by not having the airline tickets. The [Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html) says it straight and clear:

> Do not make final travel plans **or buy tickets** until you have a visa.

Now, you said "*I mean if you compare it to the UK, they focus the entire interview on your documents*". In some countries (like Russia, for example) - it is very easy to get the forged documents, and almost impossible to quickly verify their authenticity. There are even "visa helping offices" which specialize on providing their clients with fake documents "proving" employment, property ownership, bank statements and so on. This is why during the interview the interviewer has first to assess whether to trust your documents/story, and doesn't focus on your documents - the rules must be the same for all countries.

Comment: I understand "anywhere else other than India?" to mean anywhere outside the UK--where OP lives with their entirely British citizen family--other than India; Disneyland Hong Kong doesn't seem closer from the UK than Disneyland Orlando

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the OP's situation completely.

Comment: @davidvc: there is Disneyland in Paris as well, which is much closer to UK than Orlando. You're right about she probably meant "only been to India and UK"; I edited my answer.

Comment: Most likely not, as I know second-hand that Russian community in UK offers - and some people use - this kind of "service" I mentioned above.

Comment: We had original papers. I mean the rest of my family were travelling under ESTA, I had no previous convictions, why would I forge documents.

Comment: I'm in no way trying to say you did, I am just saying that SOME people have done that, and this is why the US Consulate pays much more attention to the applicant itself than to documents. Please accept my apology if it appeared this way.

Comment: Lol, no need to apologise, I was talking in general about the US consulates, why would they think I would forge documents if I had no previous convictions. My mistake, haha.

Comment: In your case I don't think the documents were an issue; more likely there were several red flags (such as those mentioned by the commentators above) which had to be addressed. I updated my answer.

Comment: We made a list of all the strong ties I have in the UK and how we would be funding it. We also went over the questions such as why are we going to Orlando Florida, and why I didn't become a British citizen. 


Why didn't you become a british citizen - I have indefinate leave which allows me to get a job and mortgage on a house, so I never really needed it, I also have land in India which I was planning on selling in the near future and having an Indian passport makes it easier for me to sell it.

Comment: Why you going Orlando Florida? - To visit universal studios (This is the question which I may have may have not addressed correctly. I should have mentioned specially why I'm going to the USA rather than somewhere closer with similar attractions. 

I won't be applying for another visa, I'm going to just make my British passport, it'll be easier, more expensive, but easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43921/discussion-between-george-y-and-zombie).

Comment: Chat link not working.